# How to design local store mechanism in note app

Tags: ios, objective-c, evernote

I'm a new developer. Recently, I'm developing a note app on iPhone with Evernote API. I have read many pdf, such as Document-based application.pdf, evernote-api.pdf and so on. But all these do is teach me how to sync with Evernote and how to design the document class. No one talks about local store mechanism.

I have designed a local store mechanism by myself; here it is:

1. Store all notebook/tag info in a plist file, such as which note in which notebook, which note has which tag, all of notebook/tag/note is represented by unique guid in plist.
2. Store each note content in their own file, with the note guid as their file name. That means however many notes the user creates, there will be the same number file on disk.

How about this local store mechanism? Is it good or bad? Any suggestion is welcome.

What's more, should I use Core Data (database) in my project?

And how can I sync with Evernote?

Answer (score 0):

The most popular way to do it is to use CoreData framework. It makes easy way to store different values of your Data Model in sqlite file in local storage of device. Look at this [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html) from apple.

Answer (score 0):

You have a valid approach. I think it's especially good, if you expect big document lengths. If you only expect short notes, you can use any of these: coredata, nsuserdefaults, basic nscoded arrays, textfiles, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @jaydee3, Because I have to sync with evernote server, the max document length could be very long, use core data in my project could be more safe, right?